# Texture Painting isn't synced with the 3D view

Tags: texture-painting

I am new to texture painting in blender.i have a cube with a texture on it and it's unwrapped i want to add some leaks on some parts on the texture when i paint in 3D view on the roughness map the leak texture appear on other parts that i don't want instead

Comment: Can you include some screen shots to show what you mean? Are you painting in the 3d view and seeing the result happen in the 2d editor as well, also misaligned? Are you checking the UV map to make sure it isn't using any overlapping faces/islands?

Comment: thank your for replying
I figured out the problem from a tutorial.
thee were some steps i didn't do

Comment: Please then make an answer to this so you can show what could happen for others and how to solve it.